# How to get inputs to properly work with classes, Python

Tags: python

As of now I am wondering how to get inputs into a class.

```
class Contact:

    def __init__(self, name = "",strengthPts = 0, power = ""):
        self.name = name
        self.power = power
        self.strengthPts = strengthPts

    def addStrengthPts(self, points):

        self.strengthPts = self.strengthPts + points
    
def main():

    namequestion = raw_input("put in a name")
    time.sleep(1)
    powerquestion = raw_input("What power would you like?")
    
    newContact = Contact(namequestion , powerquestion)
    
    print("The fabulous superhero, " + newContact.name)
    time.sleep(1)
    print(newContact.name + "'s superpower is " + newContact.power )
    print(newContact.power)


main()
```

my output is

```
The fabulous superhero, test
test's superpower is
```

My main problem, (on the bottom of the output) is that the power's input is not relaying. I am not sure if this is a simple mistake with how I added it to my "newContact" or a problem with how inputs work with classes.

Comment: The init function takes 4 args, you only provide 3. So the fourth arg will be fille with the default value, wich is "".

Comment: The powerquestion variable is set to strengthPts of the constructor, be careful with positional arguments.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your class' initializer is defined with three positional arguments (`def __init__(self, name = "",strengthPts = 0, power = ""):`). However, in this example you've passed two (`newContact = Contact(namequestion , powerquestion)`) which would mean that you're setting the value of `powerquestion` to your class instance's `strengthPts` instance variable. Since you've elected not to pass the `power` argument, it will use the default value of a blank string (`""`).

Either pass a value for the `strengthPts` positional variable, or use a named argument for `power`:

```
newContact = Contact(namequestion, power=powerquestion)
```